# Session Variable Returns Null Value in Different Web Service Methods

Tags: c#, web-services, session

I have to webmethod in which I want to use session variable something like this

```
 [WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
        public List<int> FirstMethod()
{
List<int> ListValue=getListValue();
Session["ListValue"]=ListValue;
return ListValue;
//It works fine and it also return List of integers which is ok 
}
```

Now I want to use this session value of "ListValue" in another method which is not working it returns me null value instead of List which was expected something like this

```
        [WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
                    public List<int> SecondMethod()
            {
        if(Session["ListValue"]!=null)//null value in session :(
        {List<int> ListValue=(List<int>)Session["ListValue"];
        return ListValue;
    }
    else 
    return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: try to create stateless services instead of stateful. In order words: don't use session at all.

Comment: You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method

Hope it helps

Comment: I am new at this please explain I can't understand that suggested url answer

Comment: @L-Three PLEASE elaborate

Comment: Google difference between stateless and stateful. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312969/webservices-are-stateless

Comment: No but I want to use that list from previous web method that is necessary in my second method so I have to use session or something..

Comment: That's the point: you want to AVOID that methods are dependent on each other.