# Sharing a session between two web applications

Tags: c#, session

Here's the scenario

I have two web applications, website A(c# webforms) and website B(c# MVC)

Website B is set up as an application under website A in IIS.

When a user logs onto website A I would like the user to have access to website B as though they had gone to website B and logged in.

I have created a web service that logs into website B when a user logs into Website A but this doesn't seem to have the desired effect, I'm guessing because the 2 applications don't share a session? Is  there anyway to make the 2 applications share the same session?

Comment: Why don't you use a web service instead?

Comment: if these apps under different solutions, then i dont think you can share session variable. if so, that would be insecure. as @Transcendent said, web service would help. they should look to same source to check user login status.

Comment: If you really don't wanna use a web service (which is the standard way), you can use cross-domain cookies and use them by both ends, though I don't recommend it.

Comment: I am using a web service. When someone logs into website A it calls a web service on website B. Unfortunately the user still remains logged out of website B. There's no issue with the webservice as it works if you call it locally.

Comment: You said "I have created a web service that logs into website B when a user logs into Website A". What exactly is happening at this step?

Comment: So when a user successfully logs into website A it sends the username and password to a web service in website B. The web service authenticates the username and password and if they are okay it writes the FormsAuthentication cookie.

Comment: To pass a username and password to another service is a really bad practice. Please don't do that. You should implement a token based authorization like Andrei suggested. If you google for `OAuth 2.0 Authorization`, you will find lots of information.

Comment: @Shazoo: This is not going to work, because web services are stateless. They don't set cookies or session data. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312969/webservices-are-stateless

Answer (score 2):

You can't share a web session between 2 applications, but you can move the back-end logic to a web api, and share it between the 2 websites, token based authorization, you sing in once and use the token to authorize the requests.

Comment: So when they visit Website b I have to pass a token in the query string?

Comment: If you implement the back-end as a Web API , usually the token is passed in the Authorization header field.

Comment: Can it be done with SQL using the Session? like when you use it for sharing the same session for 2 different servers?